# If statement from external config file not working

Tags: php, include, if-statement

I have a script that includes a config file (called accountsconfig.php) that contains a simple boolean:

```
<?php
$account = 'on';
?>
```

On my main script, I have a series of if else (if $account == true, do this, else this), but its always going to the else no matter what the value of $account is (As if it doesnt even get the value of $account). Heres an example of one of my ifelse:

```
 <?php
    include('accountsconfig.php');

 if ($account == 'on') { ?>
    <select name="account_number" >
         <option value="one">Account One</option>
    </select>
 <?php } else { ?>
    <h1> HIII</h1>
 <?php } ?>
```

This file and the accountsconfig.php are located in the same directory.

****UPDATE:****

If i add `<?php echo "$account" ?>` between the  in the else, it displays "off"

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 for applying the just gained knowledge regarding included config files.

Comment: @Jens haha thanks but cant seem to get the include to work :(

Comment: @ajreal I have an include with the same syntax for a different file on the same page and that one works..

Comment: (1) $account it not a boolean here, but the string 'True'. Granted, it's not the current probem, but the string 'False' is also true in boolean context, watch out for that. (2) Does your `include` even succeed? The current working directory (`getcwd`) may not be what you want. Have you enabled `display_errors` with a sufficiently high `error_reporting`?

Comment: You're boolean variables should probably contain boolean values.  I.e. `$account = true;` and `if($account === true)`

Comment: @Wrikken Yeah i display errors and im not getting any.. i have a feeling its the include that isnt working but i dont know how to check..

Comment: @Jonah Katz - quick check by outputting something from the include.

Comment: try `require()` instead of `include()` , `require` throws a fatal error if the file is not found unlike include which throws a warning (which are mostly suppressed)

Comment: I added `echo 'hello';` to the include file and its not showing up on my main page.. so i guess that confirms theres something wrong with the include

Comment: @Jonah - did you check for typos?  Is the code above copy/pasted?

Comment: @thetaiko It is indeed copied and pasted. And i just added an `echo $account` to the else and it displays 'off' when the value is True...weird

Comment: ADDED AN UPDATE TO THE QUESTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use the word true
if you do the use === in stead of == as its boolean

use another word or number to represent what you are doing 1/yes 2/no

Comment: yeah tried that. It work if i declare it directly in the script, but not if use an include.

Comment: is it working now and do the `$account = 'on';` need to be in a include file