# Can you variable from part of page be used on another?

Tags: php, variables, include

I have a variable declared between a`<?php ?>` tag. Lower down on the page, i have another `<?php ?>` where id like to use that variable. But when i echo, the variable, it displays `off`, when the value of the variable is something totally different.

(Ultimately, id like the have the variable in an external include file)

(I posted a similar question here: [If statement from external config file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929767/if-statement-from-external-config-file-no-working) )

****UPDATE****
Include file (accountsconfig.php):

```
<?php
$account = 'on';
?>
```

On my main script, I have a series of if else (if $account == true, do this, else this), but its always going to the else no matter what the value of $account is (As if it doesnt even get the value of $account). Heres an example of one of my ifelse:

```
<?php
    include('accountsconfig.php');

 if ($account == 'on') { ?>
    <select name="account_number" >
         <option value="one">Account One</option>
    </select>
 <?php } else { ?>
    <h1> <?php echo "$account" ?></h1>
 <?php } ?>
```

This file and the accountsconfig.php are located in the same directory.

Comment: Can you provide the source code?

Comment: Is this the whole thing? I don't see an echo there...

Comment: @Martin Second to last line of last code block

Comment: Sorry i didn't see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables remain consistent throughout pages, and it is also possible to declare them in one file and then use them in another. In your case it is likely something else is happening to the variable such as having it's value altered, before you echo it onto the page.

Comment: Yeah, when i try echoing the variable from the include file, it says 'off', but i dont see why this would happen..

Comment: I just tested it on my own server and it works fine, is there any other code you are using?

Comment: well theres more than one if else statement using the same include file.. but they have the same syntax as this one, you think that could mess things up?

Comment: Unless you are altering the variable, either directly, or by creating a new variable by the same name there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I just tried it on another server and it IS working. I just set up freeBSD on the server im working on so perhaps i did something wrong. Ok thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe you lost an "=" in an if statement, so that it assigned the Value instead of comparing it

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason could be, that there is a `=` sign missing.

Maybe you misspelled the `if ($account == 'off')` accidentally with a `if ($account = 'off')` somewhere. That would explain the `off` value.